# How to remove a duplicate set of characters in a string

Tags: c#, .net, windows

For example a string contains the following (the string is variable):

```
http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com
```

What would be the most efficient way of removing the duplicate url here - e.g. output would be:

```
http://www.google.com
```

Comment: "http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com".Substring(0,21)

Comment: @dbaseman The string is variable

Comment: Do you want to only remove duplicate URLs (i.e. all strings that start with http://), or all duplicate substrings?

Comment: You should give more details about the variable. Can it be something like `http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.comhttp://example.com/http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.comhttp://microsoft.comhttp://example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiency has various definitions: code size, total execution time, CPU usage, space usage, time to write the code, etc. If you want to be "efficient", you should know which one of these you're trying for.

I'd do something like this:

```
string url = "http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com";
if (url.Length % 2 == 0)
{
    string secondHalf = url.Substring(url.Length / 2);
    if (url.StartsWith(secondHalf))
    {
        url = secondHalf;
    }
}
```

Depending on the kinds of duplicates you need to remove, this may or may not work for you.

Comment: Wouldn't work with more than one duplicate though, I generally prefer Nikola Anusev's answer, just saying....

Comment: @Simon: Nikola's answer only works with URL's that start with http://. The question only specifies that there is one duplicate. Most of the other answers here are hypothesizing a bunch of other use cases that the OP didn't mention and try to handle those as well. Without knowing anything more about the application, I didn't think it was appropriate to hypothesize additional use cases that may or may not ever occur. Also, Nikola's answer achieves more generality at a cost in efficiency, since it performs additional copying; the OP explicitly asked for the "most efficient" solution.

Comment: By only trying to solve the use case that was specifically mentioned, my algorithm also manages an optimization that the others can't: not even inspecting the string if the length has an odd length, since such a string cannot contain a duplicate.

Comment: So, you can of course like whichever solution you want, but those are the reasons why, after reading the other solutions that were posted after mine, I personally still prefer my own.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that input contains only urls.

```
string input = "http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com";

// this will get you distinct URLs but without "http://" at the beginning
IEnumerable<string> distinctAddresses = input
   .Split(new[] {"http://"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Distinct();

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string distinctAddress in distinctAddresses)
{
   // when building the output, insert "http://" before each address so 
   // that it resembles the original
   output.Append("http://");
   output.Append(distinctAddress);
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

collect strings into list and use distinct, if your string has http address you can apply regex `http:.+?(?=((http:)|($))` with `RegexOptions.SingleLine`

```
var distinctList = list.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you don't know the length of the string, you don't know if something is double and you don't know what is double:

```
string yourprimarystring = "http://www.google.comhttp://www.google.com";
int firstCharacter;
string temp;
for(int i = 0; i <= yourprimarystring.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j <= yourprimarystring.length; j++)
  {
    string search = yourprimarystring.substring(i,j);
    firstCharacter = yourprimaryString.IndexOf(search);
    if(firstCharacter != -1)
    {
      temp = yourprimarystring.substring(0,firstCharacter) + yourprimarystring.substring(firstCharacter + j - i,yourprimarystring.length)
      yourprimarystring = temp;
    }
}
```

This itterates through all your elements, takes all out from first to last letter and searches for them like this:

ABCDA - searches for A finds A exludes A, thats the problem, you need to specify how long the duplication needs to be if you want to make it variable, but maybe my code helps you.